# Emulator can not download data from Internet (endless loading)

Tags: java, android, emulation

I have a problem with testing my app: it loads data from the internets and outputs it on the screen. When I try to test it with an emulator - downloading starts, but doesn't finish. When I try it with ordinary smartphone - everything is ok and data loads in one second. Here is a code, but the problem is not in it, I think:

```
final Button butTest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.parse);
        final TextView tvInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.getdata);

        butTest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                (new AsyncLoad()).execute("http://yandex.ru");
                    }



                class AsyncLoad extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                    Document doc = null;
                    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                            publishProgress(new Void[] {});
                                    try {
                                            doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                            return doc.title();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                            super.onPreExecute();
                            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(GetData.this);
                            mProgressDialog
                                            .setMessage("Download...");
                            mProgressDialog.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                            super.onPostExecute(result);
                            tvInfo.setText(result);
                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
            }
        });
```

I work in Eclipse and these are emulator settings: RAM 1024, Internal Storage 200, VM Heap 64. It works not so quickly with the other tests, but nevertheless works. With this code I can wait 10, 15, 20 minutes - it goes onPreExecute(), but not further.

Comment: have you tried closing your emulator, and starting him again

Comment: If you believe your problem is the emulator, could you give us the details about it?

Comment: Thanks for answers, I edited first post.

Answer (score 0):

Check weather you have allocated some memory in emulator settings.